# Java axis webservice - returning a list of objects leaves fields empty

Tags: java, object, service, web, axis

I created a webservice that includes a method that returns an array of objects.
The object is very simple, just two fields: String value and Integer value.

When I run the service on tomcat and use the Eclipse "Launch the Web Service Explorer" function and enter the url to the wsdl and call the function that returns the array of these objects everything works fine and I get the values as expected (for testing purposes it is a list of two objects. I get both objects containing the correct values).

Now when I create the stub classes by using wsimport and then create a testclient that calls that function I do get a list back that contains 2 items, just as expected.
However, when I want to print out the values of the fields of the objects they are empty, i.e. integer value is 0 and string value is null.

Any suggestions on what the issue could be? I would assume there is some kind of error happening when I create the classes with wsimport..